# Kinect: Assign joint name to Joint

Tags: c#, kinect

I try to assign a name to each joint. The calling function is:

```
 for(int t=0;t<body._body.Length;t++)
        {
            DrawPoint(body._body[t], canvs,col_t,col_i);
        }
```

and the full DrawPoint function:

```
 public static void DrawPoint(JointData _joint, Canvas canvs, Color col_t, Color col_i)
    {

        #region convert JointData to Kinect.Joint type
        Joint currentJoint;
        currentJoint.TrackingState = JointTrackingState.NotTracked;
        currentJoint.Position.X = -1;
        currentJoint.Position.Y = -1;
        currentJoint.Position.Z = -1;
        currentJoint.JointType = JointType.AnkleLeft;

        if (_joint._TrackState == "Tracked")
            currentJoint.TrackingState = JointTrackingState.Tracked;
        if (_joint._TrackState == "Inferred")
            currentJoint.TrackingState = JointTrackingState.Inferred;
        if (_joint._TrackState == "NotTracked")
            currentJoint.TrackingState = JointTrackingState.NotTracked;

        if (_joint._jointType == "AnkleLeft")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.AnkleLeft;
        if (_joint._jointType == "AnkleRight")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.AnkleRight;
        if (_joint._jointType == "ElbowLeft")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.ElbowLeft;
        if (_joint._jointType == "ElbowRight")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.ElbowRight;
        if (_joint._jointType == "FootLeft")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.FootLeft;
        if (_joint._jointType == "FootRight")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.FootRight;
        if (_joint._jointType == "HandLeft")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.HandLeft;
        if (_joint._jointType == "HandRight")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.HandRight;
        if (_joint._jointType == "HandTipLeft")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.HandTipLeft;
        if (_joint._jointType == "HandTipRight")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.HandTipRight;
        if (_joint._jointType == "Head")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.Head;
        if (_joint._jointType == "HipLeft")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.HipLeft;
        if (_joint._jointType == "HipRight")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.HipRight;
        if (_joint._jointType == "KneeLeft")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.KneeLeft;
        if (_joint._jointType == "KneeRight")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.KneeRight;
        if (_joint._jointType == "Neck")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.Neck;
        if (_joint._jointType == "ShoulderLeft")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.ShoulderLeft;
        if (_joint._jointType == "ShoulderRight")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.ShoulderRight;
        if (_joint._jointType == "SpineBase")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.SpineBase;
        if (_joint._jointType == "SpineMid")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.SpineMid;
        if (_joint._jointType == "SpineShoulder")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.SpineShoulder;
        if (_joint._jointType == "ThumbLeft")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.ThumbLeft;
        if (_joint._jointType == "ThumbRight")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.ThumbRight;
        if (_joint._jointType == "WristLeft")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.WristLeft;
        if (_joint._jointType == "WristRight")
            currentJoint.JointType = JointType.WristRight;

        currentJoint.Position.X = (float)Convert.ToDouble(_joint._position[0]);
        currentJoint.Position.Y = (float)Convert.ToDouble(_joint._position[1]);
        currentJoint.Position.Z = (float)Convert.ToDouble(_joint._position[2]);
        #endregion

        #region drawing

        Color currentColor = Colors.Blue;

        if (currentJoint.TrackingState == TrackingState.NotTracked) return;

        //if (currentJoint.TrackingState == TrackingState.Inferred) currentColor = Colors.Yellow;
        if (currentJoint.TrackingState == TrackingState.Inferred) currentColor = col_i;
        //if (currentJoint.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracked) currentColor = Colors.Green;
        if (currentJoint.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracked) currentColor = col_t;

        currentJoint = ScaleTo(currentJoint, canvs.ActualWidth, canvs.ActualHeight);

        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse
        {
            Width = 8,
            Height = 8,
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(currentColor)
        };

        Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, currentJoint.Position.X - ellipse.Width / 2);
        Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, currentJoint.Position.Y - ellipse.Height / 2);

        canvs.Children.Add(ellipse);
        #endregion

    }
```

However, I get the error at the line

```
currentJoint.TrackingState = JointTrackingState.NotTracked;
```

that " Use of unassigned local variable 'currentJoint' "
and subsequently make `currentJoint.Position` and `currentJoint.JointType` return errors of "Cannot modify the return value of 'Joint.Position' because it is not a variable " and "Property or indexer 'Joint.JointType' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" respectively.

How could I fix these errors? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I could see that might be wrong is that `Joint currentJoint;` might need to be changed to `Joint currentJoint = new Joint();`